# How to save the window state at wxWidgets?

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm constructing a UI using wxWidgets.

In my GUI, I generate a window (wxFrame class) which is accessible through pushing a bitmap button. In that window, I also perform some tasks, again pushing some bitmap buttons and diabling them etc. But I can't close and reopen that window with the state saved. I always have to re-initialize it, and this is very impractical.

How can I save the state of my window? I checked the internet, it's suggested to use wxPersistent class but this class is missing in my wxWidgets.

Thank you for any help,

Best Regards.

Comment: Does it have to persist across program launches? Or do you just need persistence between window openings/closings within the program lifetime?

Comment: I need it within the program lifetime. The whole process can be killed after I close the program. But during the lifetime, I want to save the state of the other windows which I open using buttons.

Comment: FYI wxPersistentXXX is only available in wxWidgets 2.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of destroying the window every time, you can just hide it with the [`wxWindow::Show()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowshow) member function, passing `false` as the argument, when you receive a [`wxCloseEvent`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxcloseevent.html#wxcloseevent). You then veto the `wxCloseEvent` to prevent WxWidgets from destroying your window:

```
// In your close handler:
if(evt.CanVeto()) // Where evt is a wxCloseEvent
{
    Show(false);  // Hide window
    evt.Veto();   // Prevent window destruction
}
```

This should remove it from the screen, but all the initialized parts should still be there. If you need to show it again, call the `Show()` method again with `true`.

Comment: Marvelous!! Thank you! I modified my event handler function and it works! Is there also a way to modify the "x" - closing button on the top so that it doesn't destroy but hides the window?

Comment: You need to `Veto()` the `wxCloseEvent`. For example, you can probably put something like this: `if(evt.CanVeto()) { Show(false); evt.Veto(); }` in your close handler. Basically, if we can veto the close, we veto it to prevent WxWidgets from destroying the window.